# Returning identity value using Azure Functions SQL extension

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I am working on a simple REST API using the SQL extension for Azure Functions as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-javascript).

Now i have a table in my Azure SQL database with a primary-key identity column. I am using an Output binding in a HTTP-triggered Azure function for inserting a row in the table:

```
...
{
  "name": "aRow",
  "type": "sql",
  "direction": "out",
  "commandText": "[dbo].[MYTABLE]",
  "commandType": "Text",
  "connectionStringSetting": "..."
},
...
```

This is working perfectly and the identity column is being incremented as expected. Now, naturally, i want to return the identity ID of the inserted row to the client. I don't think this feature is built in at the moment, therefor i was hoping that someone out there has solved this in a neat way or at least can point me in a direction.

I have tried adding an Input binding to the above function that querys the row where ID = @@IDENTITY, but it seems like the bindings aren't executed in the same scope or in the correct order. Either way, there is no match for this query. That would've been a neat solution though.

Answer (score 1):

I have just started an Azure function project and this was my story as well.
Apparently, as you already know, the "sql" output binding from Azure function is not an all-around solution - unlike other web frameworks. So at the time of typing this, I couldn't find any solutions relating to the "sql" binding to support retrieving the just-inserted(updated) record id.

Instead, I followed the sample code https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-sql-db-todo-backend-func-node and it works well.

In short, I still had to write all the SPs and queries myself and use **tedious** to execute the SPs and get the returned values.

Hope this help

Comment: I have since stumbled upon the sql binding direction “in-out” which to me sounds like something useful in this case, but i haven’t got to test it yet and its poorly documented.